# Div height is not extending to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I have a page layout for a website I'm developing that goes something like this:

```
-------------------------------------Top Bar-------------------------------------
|                                                                               |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------Content (Has a dark filter that goes over the main background image)-----
------------ Main Content---------------------------|-------------SideBar--------
|                                                   |                           |
|                                                   |                           |
|                                                   |                           |
|                                                   |                           |
|                                                   |                           |
|                                                   |                           |
|                                                   |                           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The  in my page is usually a photo that, for design purposes, I need to apply a dark filter. So I create a .content class that serves that purpose, and everything (except for the top bar) goes inside it.

The problem I have is that, when the content in the .main-content container exceeds the page height, the filter does not go to the bottom of the page. I have the .content height at 100%, as well as the body and the html tags.

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    /*10px = 1em*/
    line-height: 1.4;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.top-bar {
    width:100%;
    height:58px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.top-bar.user {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 58px;
    /* = top bar height*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.main-content {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried to create the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/apGgd/3/

Has you can see, as the table expands, the filter (the grey background) does not go along it. However if you remove the 'height:100%' from the .content, the issue goes away.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand the issue. The issue seems to fix when you eliminate the height declarations in the `.content` class. Are you looking for an explanation?

Comment: The point is that removing the height: 100%, would mess up with some other pages I got. However since this seems to be the only solution (or at least the most obvious one) I'll adopt it and try to adapt the other pages to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it works is when you remove the `height:100%` is because you don't need to explicitly declare it. What you want is `height:auto; min-height:100%;`. This will ensure that the height is at least 100%, but will fill the table as needed, which I think is the behavior you want.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apGgd/9/)

Comment: I would suggest removing the height declarations entirely if you get the result you want without it... no height declaration by default is always equal to height:auto anyway as far as i know...

Comment: @AntonioVasilev -  if he wants to have it stretch to bottom even if the content doesnt allow it, then he needs to declare `min-height:100%;` certain browsers (older versions of Firefox) require an explicit declaration of `height` for `min-height` to apply, otherwise it will switch back to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

you just delete height:100%; from the .content section and add an overflow:show;(if the previous is not worked)